# there's a problem with my texture or something

Tags: texturing

Im not sure what I've done wrong but some reason their is a random whiteish line in my texture for my dinosaur.[image]

Comment: Seems to be a mesh problem.
Could you provide the file or at least a screenshot of the mesh without materials?

Comment: not the same subdivisions between this model and another one, maybe

Comment: I solved it,  you were right lemon